# Bash- awk one liner { print every third line of a text file }

Tags: bash, awk

So, I'm trying to display/print every third line of a file.

So it'll be like

```
    third line



    sixth line 



    ninth line 




    twelfth line.
```

It's gotta be a one line awk command.

Comment: Do you want all those blank lines in the output?

Comment: Don't just ask us for code.  What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter on the line numbers; only match those divisible by 3.

```
awk 'NR % 3 == 0' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

by awk

```
awk '!(NR%3)' file.txt
```

by `sed`

```
sed -n '3,${p;n;n;}' file.txt
```